# No property getAll found for type Department

Tags: java, spring

Why getAll() can't be declared in JPA interface?

My entity Department for example:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "department")
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

The repository:

```
@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> {
    public Optional<Department> findOneById(Long id);
    public Optional<Department> findOneByName(String name);
    public List<Department> findAllByNameOrDescriptionContains(String name, String description);
    public List<Department> getAll();
}
```

but only for the method `getAll` it threw an exception `Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.myProject.repository.DepartmentRepository.getAll()! No property getAll found for type Department!`

Why did this happen?

Comment: Read the Javadoc for JpaRepository: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html

Comment: There's no defined method for ```getAll()```? So I have to define it by myself or to use ```findAll()```?

Comment: `findAll()` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use findAll() for get all List of Department.
here you can check all methods of JpaRepository [JpaReposiotory methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html)